Delete all items from a sharepoint list with the REST Api
Is there a method to delete all items from a sharepoint list using the REST API ?  Preferably not using a Loop over all items and deleting individual item ?
I have got to the point where I can delete entire list with the 'DELETE' request to the URL
https://<myOrganization>.sharepoint.com/sites/path/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Listname')

However, at this time I can't delete and recreate the list.  I need to remove individual items.  I am using POSTMAN, that is why I prefer not to do do in the loop, and also, I am not sure what is the API limit (if there is such thing)

Dmitriy. I am not sure if you are still looking for a solution, but there is a wonderful tutorial by Paul Murana. Hope this one fulfills your expectation.

Thank you.  I did resort to using power automate .. using it without templates or variables ...
The tutorial has a better way
